# Integrating MoPub with cocoapods - swift

Tags: swift, cocoapods

In my podfile I have

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Penguin Rush' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Penguin Rush

  pod 'mopub-ios-sdk'

  target 'Penguin RushTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
```

As you can note I am doing use_frameworks!

I also created a bridging header, which I shouldn't have to do, but I am still unable to find the SDK.

Under my build settings I have Objective-C Bridging Header pointed to Penguin Rush/PenguinRush-BridgingHeader.h

I have also pointed Framework Search Paths to "Pods/**"

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4.2 Use mopub sdk by import mopub

**import MoPub**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let sdkConfig = MPMoPubConfiguration(adUnitIdForAppInitialization: "Your ad unit id")

    MoPub.sharedInstance().initializeSdk(with: sdkConfig) {

    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Neverminderino.

I followed this guide:

http://onebigfunction.com/ios/2015/12/31/mopub-mo-problems/

I just kept my own bridging header, pointed my Obj-C Bridging Header in build settings to that and called it done.